# Move project from Ant to Maven and break it up

Tags: java, maven, ant

I have an existing web project which currently uses Ant. I have tasks that:

- create the jar based on only certain packages for other applications which use this project as a dependency
- create the war file for the app

and a lot of others.

Separately I have a webservice project which uses the jar built by the previous application. This project uses Maven.

Now what I want to achieve is to move the first project to Maven, break it into `core` and `web`, and then move the webservice project into the first one. 
So the result will be a multi-module project:

- core
- ui
- webservice

Is it possible to move the sources that deal with the web delivery mechanism into the ui module (which will be a war in Maven), or I need to keep the sources in the core?

What would the best approach to do this be?

Should I look into Maven profiles?

I am a novice with Maven, so I am unsure on how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can achieve what you want with Maven. I would break the modules like this:

**Core**:

```
<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>core</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

**UI**:

```
<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>ui</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<!-- Dependends on core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

**Web service:**

```
<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>ws</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<!-- Also Dependends on core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

**Main Project**:

```
<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>ui</module>
    <module>ws</module>
</modules>
```

Then, in Core / UI and Web service you declare myapp as the parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

For further info refer to:

- [Introduction to the POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html): Particularly: Inheritance and Project Aggregation
- [Maven by Example: Chapter 6. A Multi-module Project](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html): For a sample project
- [Multi-modules projects](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects): For the folder structure

Comment: Yeah that'd would be a great solution, but how can I actually break my code into core and web? A couple of packages are dealing with web stuff only (they basically extends/implements/deal with struts classes). I guess I would need one more module: core, web (as a jar), war and webservice. What do you think?

Comment: Just move "core" packages to the core module. UI - or web (the war module) - has it own `src` folder for web / struts specific stuff (just declare the right dependencies for [struts](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts)); classes there will be able to use the core classes (since UI declares core as a dependency, a jar file containing the core classes will be copied to `/WEB-INF/lib` by maven). What I mean is, I see no reason to introduce one more jar just to hold struts logic.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, I will try to achieve what you just described, I was under the impression that I could not add source code to a packaging = war.